# higher order method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions

I have a React.js component and I'd like to define a higher order method like so -

```
updater: function (path) {
  return function (value) {
    this.setState(this.modules.setter.set(this.state, path, value)) 
  }
}
```

Where `this.modules.setter.set` returns an updated version of the state, with a new `value` lying along the specified `path`.

This is in the hopes of being able to define a method like so -

`updateUserStreet: this.updater('user.address.street')`

I have no problem with creating the desired `this.modules.setter.set`, however I'm having trouble using a higher-order method in general.
The console is telling me that `this.updater is not a function`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is `updater` defined on the same object as `updateUserStreet`? If yes, this is a duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/218196)

Comment: It is, though I think it might be worth leaving it as its own question since the answer is somewhat specific to React components and so would not be obvious from the answers to that question. That answer being - one should define these properties-defined-in-terms-of-other-properties in the .getInitialState method of the React Component. This solution is of the general flavor of the answers to the other question, which writ large involve giving the object a constructor function and defining those properties there. I could be wrong though, it just wasn't obvious to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define `updateUserStreet` within the `.getInitialState` method of the React Component like so

```
getInitialState: function () {
  this.updateUserStreet = this.updater('user.address.street');
  return {...}
}
```

the `updateUserStreet` method will now be available within any other method defined on the React component

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `updater` is actually a reserved word in React components.  It's used to maintain the component's lifecycle and state.

I couldn't find it in the docs directly, but found it mentioned briefly here: http://reactkungfu.com/2016/03/dive-into-react-codebase-handling-state-changes/

Try renaming `updater` to a different name.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!